# Were there any Franz Kafka references in The Amazing Spider-Man 2?

Tags: spider-man, marvel, the-amazing-spider-man-2

When we first see

> Electro at the Ravencroft Institute,

we see a doctor whose name was Kafka. Was this just a coincidence? Or were there any references from the works of [Franz Kafka](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franz_Kafka) in the movie?

I thought that the transformation of Max from a normal human into Electro was kinda like Kafka's [Metamorphosis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Metamorphosis), and maybe this is why the doctor's name was Kafka.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Possibly because a wee bit of research ([the Wikipedia page for the Dr. Kafka comics character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ashley_Kafka) is linked to from [the Amazing Spider-Man 2 Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Amazing_Spider-Man_2)) would have answered the question. In general, Stack Exchange sites aren’t intended to duplicate information that’s already readily available from other reference sources on the internet. However, I think sciFi.SE is a bit more permissive in that regard, so I think your question is fine.

Comment: I don't see any mention of Franz Kafka on these pages. I had already seen them.

Comment: Ah, I see. Your question reads as if you thought the movie character’s name was a reference to Franz Kafka, rather than being an existing character’s name from the comics.

Comment: Yes. Also, if there were any references to kafka's works

Answer (score 4):

There’s a psychiatrist called Dr. Ashley Kafka at the Ravencroft Institute in the comics:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ashley_Kafka

I think this is the simplest explanation for the movie character’s name (although I haven’t read any Franz Kafka, so maybe there were some references I didn’t spot).

And [@Keen](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/1027/keen) has found [a fascinating Vanity Fair interview](http://www.vanityfair.com/vf-hollywood/spider-man-real-life-dr-kafka) which claims that the comics character was originally named after a fairly distant relative of Franz Kafka, therapeutic hypnotist Frayda Kafka:

> *So at one point along the way the legendary comic-book writer J.M. DeMatteis walks in your door.*
>
> Yes...he said he wanted to go to a hypnotist, for creative purposes to help with his writing and research. But he wanted a hypnotist who was a Baba lover. Somebody gave him my card. He doesn’t remember who. But he carried my card for years. Then one day we met at a meeting and he recognized my name and pulled the card out of his pocket.
>
> *So you are absolutely the inspiration of Spider-Man’s Dr. Kafka, right? He told you beforehand?*
>
> Yes, he said he was thinking of doing it, and I was thrilled. You know, why not?

Comment: Per the appendix in the Starbooks Classics translation of _The Metamorphosis_, Dr. Ashley Kafka is a reference to author Franz Kafka.

Comment: @BrianS Did that appendix provide a source for that assertion?

Comment: Not that I saw, but I only looked at the Google Books result, which doesn't contain all of the content.

Comment: @BrianS But, there's this: http://www.vanityfair.com/vf-hollywood/spider-man-real-life-dr-kafka

Comment: @Keen: fabulous find. Minus one to the Starbooks Classics translation of *The Metamorphosis*. I reckon that link is worth an answer.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Just add it to yours.